# Where best to place "pour autant"?

Tags: adverbes, ordre-des-mots

> {In an article}: Loin du mouvement color block, le look monochrome ne veut **pour autant** pas dire ennuyeux ni toc monomaniaque.

I myself tend to place "pour autant" right after "pas" or at the end of the sentence:

> Loin du mouvement color block, le look monochrome ne veut  pas **pour autant** dire  ennuyeux ni toc monomaniaque.
>
> Loin du mouvement color block, le look monochrome ne veut  pas dire  ennuyeux ni toc monomaniaque **pour autant**.

Another possibility might be:

> Loin du mouvement color block, le look monochrome ne veut  pas dire **pour autant** ennuyeux ni toc monomaniaque.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the best solution is :

> Loin du mouvement color block, le look monochrome ne veut **pour autant** pas dire ennuyeux ni toc monomaniaque.

This solution is also correct :

> Loin du mouvement color block, le look monochrome ne veut pas dire ennuyeux ni toc monomaniaque **pour autant**.

Answer (score 0):

I will say :

> Loin du mouvement color block, le look monochrome ne veut pour **autant**
>   **pas** dire ennuyeux ni toc monomaniaque.

'Pour autant' comes from 'Pour autant que je sache' which mean : 'Maybe I'm wrong'.